# perl regex to read contents between double quotes

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file which contains information something like this:

```
TAG1      "file1.txt"
```

some additional lines

```
TAG2      "file2.txt"
```

some more lines

```
TAG3      "file3.txt".
```

Now, I want to read what is inside the double quotes and assign it to variable ( something like `$var1 = file1.txt`  `$var2 = file2.txt` `$var3 = fil3.txt)`. Can anyone guild me how to do this.?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your goal by

1. using regular expression

   ```
   my @files;
   while (my $line = <>) {
           if (m/"([^"]+)"/) {
                   push @files, $1;
           }
   }
   ```
2. using `split()`

   ```
   my @files;
   while (my $line = <>) {
           my (undef, $file, undef) = split /"/, $line, 3;
           push @files, $file;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Except for the period after `"file3.txt".` (which I suspect is a artifact from posting the question), your data appears to be a CSV file with tabs.

If that's the case, I advise you to parse the file with [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { sep_char => "\t" } )
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

my @files;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.csv';
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    push @files; $row->[1];
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;

print "@files";
```